# Skip one or more constraints in Django form.is_valid()

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

Given the following model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    role = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=128, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
```

I need that `form.is_valid()` would skip the `unique` constraint on `email` field.

It's essential, that emails would be `unique`, however in one particular `view` I wanna use `get_or_create`, which doesn't seem to work:

```
if form.is_valid():
    usr, usr_created = models.User.objects.get_or_create(email=form.email)
    <...>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

`unique=True` creates a database constraint that checks for the uniqueness of the field. By its very design this disallows non-unique values, and the only way to circumvent this is to remove the constraint.

If the problem is that you want to allow multiple empty values, you can set `null=True`. Multiple `NULL` values are still considered unique by the constraint.

Comment: @NarūnasK That's a completely different question, one to which I don't have the answer since you haven't included many details of your problem.

Comment: I dare to say, that question remains the same, I just added potential use case :)

Comment: @NarūnasK If the question remains the same, then surely the answer remains the same as well, right? ;) Anyway, I can't tell you why `get_or_create()` doesn't work unless you tell how its behaviour differs from what you expect.

Comment: I get validation error: `User with this Email already exists.`, which is expected, because test email is in fact in the database, therefore I wanna use `get_or_create()`. I suppose in the end I will have to use `form.errors` and verify if apart from `email` error there any other.

Answer (score 0):

Don't list the field you want to override in the fields list and create a new custom field in the ModelForm:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["role", "name"]

    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=128)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(PatientForm, self).save(commit=False)
        instance.email= self.cleaned_data.get("email")
        return instance.save(commit)
```